# Word wrapping is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

This I just created a div. and I give a `White-space: Normal` function for word wrapping when I type the contents. This function is working in Chrome,Opera and Safari Browser. But the words are not wrapping in Mozilla Firefox and Edge  browser. And also I tried the `Word-wrap: break-word` function. This is also not working. Please give me a solution.

```html
<div class = "list-name-field" id = "SAVE_LIST" style = "white-space: normal; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ccc; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Add a List..."></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `word-break: break-all` if you need to break a long word

```html
<div class = "list-name-field" id = "SAVE_LIST" style = "white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ccc; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Add a List..."></div>
```

Comment: This was Working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1g86whpd/)

Add to CSS:

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Comment: I tried this code. But this was not working in Firefox. I don't Know why. Thank for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Use the following property:

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;//For firefox
word-wrap: break-word;
```

And html:

```
<div class = "list-name-field" id = "SAVE_LIST" style =" width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto;  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ccc; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Add a List..."></div>
```